# Visual C++ Opening a second form

Tags: forms, visual-c++, button

I have a project that contains two forms, Form1.h and Form2.h.

The .cpp files of each is test.cpp and Form2.cpp.

I want to open the second form from the first through a button click, of which I already have the code for, placed inside the button1_Click method:

```
Form2 ^ form = gcnew Form2;
form->Show();
```

I have furthermore placed the include file in Form1.h (#include "Form2.h"), however I keep getting the following errors:

```
error C2065: 'Form2' : undeclared identifier

error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Form2'

error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier

error C2227: left of '->Show' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

1>          type is ''unknown-type''

1>  Generating Code...

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have been searching a solution for a couple of days... none of which worked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included Form1.h in test.cpp?

Comment: Switching #include "Form1.h" in test.cpp to #include "Form2.h" results in:   C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Form1'            Including both results the same problem.

Comment: Have you actually declared the classes in the header files? Or is that done in the cpp.

Comment: I have modified nothing to the source code beyond #include statements and the button1_Click method.

Comment: Show us what Form2.h contains. It should declare the class Form2.