# C++ Windows Form Application accessing another form on button click

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have created Windows Form Application with C++ in Visual Studio 2010. I have created two forms (Form1, Form2). I added button to Form1. Now I want on button click go to Form2 (hide Form1).

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }
```

What is the right way to do this?

I've tried this:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Form2->ShowDialog();
             }
```

But that gives me this error while building:

```
error C2065: 'Form2' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->ShowDialog' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

Comment: As the error points out .. It cannot find "Form2" .. You need to declare an object of "Form2"

Comment: I have created Form2 by adding new Item

Comment: Yes.Still you need to be declare an object .. By adding Form you do not create an object , you create a class declaration

Comment: So. Should I declare it button1_Click() function? Can you pleaseprovide code snippet?

Comment: Look into this .. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728015/visual-c-opening-a-second-form

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include in "Form1.h":

```
#include "Form2.h"
```

Then in Form1.h:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Form2 ^ form2 = gcnew Form2;
                 form2->Show();
             }
```